# Travelling to London with a Misdemeanor

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, criminal-records

We are travelling from the USA to the UK/Scotland/Ireland for a family wedding/ tourism in November 2019 (for 2 weeks).

My husband was convicted of Assault,Family Violence in 2017 (misdemeanor). He’s a US citizen and in Texas.   Complicated story, but he should never have been arrested, albeit for a rogue cop that was "after" an arrest. The "victim" (daughter) told cops not to press charges and he did anyway under The State!

No sentence, just time served (3 days).

Anyway, could this affect him entering the UK?  If so, should he apply for a Visa? We haven't travelled to the UK before.  I'm Australian, so won't have an issue.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You didn't mention the nationality of your husband, nor where the offence took place. Blaming a "rogue cop" or saying it "shouldn't have happened" isn't likely to help your case, and it is well known that the victim can try to protect the assailant in domestic cases. So it would be better to put your opinions on one side and focus on the fact that it did happen.

Comment: You need to start the visa process as early as possible to allow time in case of extra processing.

Comment: For clarity, what is his citizenship and what was the sentence? A criminal conviction is grounds for refusal of entry clearance or leave to enter the UK in some circumstances, see Immigration Rules 320 (2) and (18) https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

Comment: You should know that Ireland is a separate country from the UK. If you are traveling there you should check out the visa situation there.